# Tag followers are getting their mails too quickly

Tags: support, stack-exchange, timezone, subscription, tag-filters

I have followed some tags, but I'm getting the mail of the most interesting questions around 6.50 am. That mail isn't from the day before, but from the current day (that day that is only 6 hours and 50 minutes far).

Maybe their are some problems with timezones, etc. But for me, it sounds a bit stupid.
**There are going to be more interesting questions today, after 6.50am.**

If I'm getting the most interesting questions of the day before on the current day, I don't care. But I think I'm missing the real interesting questions.

Comment: For me this has not been a problem. I get the things I expect from this great site,

Answer (score 1):

Our day is based on UTC 00:00:00 to UTC 23:59:59.

If you elect to receive emails daily (remember you can select every 15 minutes, every 3 hours, or daily) then you'll get them after the UTC day ends, reflecting questions in your tags for the previous UTC day.

I suggest you switch to every 3 hours if this is a concern.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/